# Visual Studio 2010 crashes and unable to customize context menus

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to customize code window (Editor context menu | Code window) context menu in my VS 2010 Ultimate and there is no elements for edit there http://habreffect.ru/files/56f/cc371d8a9/Capture.png (In real context menu all the elements are exists, also elements are exists for most other menus in customize window) and VS crashes when i'm trying to add new menu
I have tried to reset all the menus in the customize window but this trouble appears again in a few days. This problem appears on both my PC and my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you send Microsoft a bug-report, at Microsoft Connect.